# Graphclient misses token on second login

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, blazor-server-side

I've created an blazor server application that allows a user to sign in with a Microsoft Account (via an Entra app registration).
In the program.cs I add GraphClient to it.

When the user signs in, the graphclient is initialized properly and I get get info with it.

However, when I start stop the the application the user doesn't need to sign in and is Authenticated due to the .aspnetcore.cookie. This is nice, but the graphclient is now not initialized anymore and fails with error:MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call

Can I either
a) initialize the graphclient so that it is working properly (preference)
b) remove the authentication cookie with code, so I can remove it and reload the page when needed.

My authentication setup in program.cs:

```
var graphScopes = builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? Array.Empty<string>();
var graphConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Prompt = "select_account";
        options.MaxAge = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            context.HandleResponse();
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        };

    })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(graphScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(graphConfig)
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

My code in the page is in OnAfterRenderAsync:

```
var authenticationState = await Provider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
if (!(authenticationState.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)) return;
var user = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

The last line throws the error when the user was already signed in.

I already tried to request the Token via the ITokenAcquisition interface or derive it from the IHttpContextAccesor, so I could build up a new Graphclient in the code. However I assume there is a better solution (hopefully in the program.cs)

If I manually delete the cookie and refresh the page, everything runs smoothly

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the client will have a valid token when the use authenticates but after, the session exists, your client doesnt have the access token.

You need to pass an authentication provider to the Graph Client that will handle this for you. See [Use Graph API with ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=graph-sdk-4) for guidance on how to achieve that

You are looking at something like the client builder and authentication provider in `GraphClientExtensions.cs` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=graph-sdk-4)

Comment: I am on Blazor Server